# Why does this random number sometimes get set to -1?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

Every now and again, the following comes out as -1

```
int randomIndex = random() % [directionsArray count] - 1;
```

The init method for this class is where directionsArray is created and `srand()` is called. It looks like this

```
- (id) initSprite
{
    if ( ( self = [super initSprite] ) ) {

        speed = 1;

        directionsArray = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:STRING_CONSTANT, STRING_CONSTANT, nil] retain];
        srand(time(NULL));
        [self pickRandomDirection];


    }
    return self;
}

- (void) pickRandomDirection
{
    int randomIndex = random() % [directionsArray count] - 1; // This sometimes comes out as -1??
}
```

At the moment, I'm working around it by using `abs(randomIndex)`, but that's cheating and I should probably know what's going on for future reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because 0 - 1 equals -1.

```
    random() % [directionsArray count] - 1;
```

What if random() returns 0 here ? You get 0%[directionsArray count] - 1; which is -1, since % has precedence over -

Perhaps you want `random() % ([directionsArray count] - 1);`

Comment: All great answers, but this is the one that made me go "oh right... of course it does..."

Answer (score 5):

Does % have precedence over -1? If it does then when the remainder is 0 minuses 1 will result in negative one.

Answer (score 2):

Know your [operator precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence).  If in doubt, use parentheses:

```
int randomIndex = random() % ([directionsArray count] - 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why nobody else has mentioned this, but the solution (in your case) is actually to not subtract at all.

As you're probably aware, indexes are zero-based. Remainders likewise start at 0, and they go up to the divisor minus one and then loop around. Consider, for example, the case of `count == 3`:

- 0 % 3 = 0
- 1 % 3 = 1
- 2 % 3 = 2
- 3 % 3 = 0

Doing the division first, as Stephen Canon and Jonathan Fischoff already told you, will cause you to subtract 1 from these valid indexes, causing the problem you saw.

Doing the division second is not much better: It solves the problem of coming up with an index of -1, but you're still cutting off the last possible index:

- 0 % (count - 1 = 2) = 0
- 1 % 2 = 1
- 2 % 2 = 0
- 3 % 2 = 1

Notice how index 3 never comes up.

Divide only; cut out the subtraction.

Also, indexes are normally `NSUInteger` (an *unsigned* integral type, unlike `int`, which is signed) in Cocoa and Cocoa Touch.

Comment: This answer should be up higher, as it actually codes what the asker intended.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't use `random`**

Use `arc4random` instead.

Now that issue is solved, you're subtracting 1 from the randomization expression, which, in the case of `arc4random % len` returning `0`, you'd be subtracting `1` from that, which is `-1`.

Comment: In some cases, using `arc4random` instead of `random` is a good idea. In others, it makes no sense whatsoever. Picking a “random” direction for a sprite will generally fall in the latter category. However, the OP should be using `srandom` rather than `srand` if he’s sticking with `random`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend arc4random.  It seems to be the easiest to use and best rnd available in the SDK.

```
arc4random() % [directionsArray count];
```